# c# to return all customers in netsuite by stage

Tags: c#, netsuite

using c#, I need to get all customers in NetSuite where the stage is ._customer

I'm using this at the moment:

```
  private void ReturnAllCustomers()
    {
        // Instantiate a search object for customers. 
        CustomerSearch custSearch = new CustomerSearch();
        CustomerSearchBasic custSearchBasic = new CustomerSearchBasic();


        // Search the customer status which is a list field (16,13,15) 
        String statusKeysValue = "16,13,15";
        SearchMultiSelectField status = null;
        if (statusKeysValue != null && !statusKeysValue.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            status = new SearchMultiSelectField();
            status.@operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
            status.operatorSpecified = true;
            string[] nskeys = statusKeysValue.Split(new Char[] { ',' });

            RecordRef[] recordRefs = new RecordRef[statusKeysValue.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < nskeys.Length; i++)
            {
                RecordRef recordRef = new RecordRef();
                recordRef.internalId = nskeys[i];
                recordRefs[i] = recordRef;
            }
            status.searchValue = recordRefs;
            custSearchBasic.entityStatus = status;
        }

        custSearch.basic = custSearchBasic;

        // Invoke search() web services operation 
        SearchResult response = _service.search(custSearch);

        // Process response
        if (response.status.isSuccess)
        {
            // Process the records returned in the response and print to console
            // Get more records with pagination
            if (response.totalRecords > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= response.totalRecords; i++)
                {
                    processCustomerSearchResponse(response);
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }

    }
```

It's borrowed from a similar idea that searches based on status.  That returns a strange subset of my customers but not all of them.

I also tried something like this:
custSearchBasic.stage = CustomerStage._customer;

But it's coughing on that because it wants that stage to be a "SearchEnumMultiSelectField" type.

Netsuite's help is useless so any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The customer stage value is buried in the (wonderful) documentation.

```
CustomerSearch cs = new CustomerSearch();
cs.basic = new CustomerSearchBasic();
cs.basic.stage = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
cs.basic.stage.@operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
cs.basic.stage.operatorSpecified = true;
cs.basic.stage.searchValue = new string[] { "PROSPECT" };
```

Comment: thanks; I'll give that a try.  my company may end up just hiring a consultant that already has knowledge of netsuite to get us started since they're help and code samples are useless.